# Hibernate @OneToMany not saving null values inside my List

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

I am using postgresql database and I have the following tables: "user", "game" and "game_user" all inside the schema "allin". In my web application I'm using Hibernate 4.3.5, Spring MVC, and spring data jpa.

In my Game class I have the following OneToMany relationship:

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(schema = "allin", name = "game_user",  
joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "game_id") }, 
inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id",nullable=true) })
private List<User> users;
```

And here is my unit test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { ServletInitializer.class, SecurityWebApplicationInitializer.class, WebMvcConfig.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
public class GameRepositoryTest
{
    @Autowired
    private GameService gameService;

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @Test
    public void testRepostory()
    {
        List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();

        users.add(userService.findByUsername("luizcarlosfx"));

        users.add(null);

        users.add(null);

        Game newGame = new Game(users, 10);

        Game savedGame = gameService.save(newGame);

        assertNotNull(savedGame);

        Game getGame = gameService.findById(savedGame.getId());

        assertEquals("There must be the same amount of users in the craeted game and in the saved game",newGame.getUsers().size(), getGame.getUsers().size());

    }
}
```

When I run my unit test I get the following error: "There must be the same amount of users in the craeted game and in the saved game. expected:<3> but was:<1>."

The problem is that hibernate is not saving the null values that are inside the list of users, and I need to save my guest players as null, because they don't have any user. This part of the application must save games history of my multiplayer game.

My question is how to make hibernate save also the null values?

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id",nullable=true) })
```

would not allow you to save a `Null-Object`. You cannot save a `Null` (as object, but as value). `Null` is a not existing object. EVEN if you could manage to save a row *filled with null-values* - how would you assign this to **ANY** guest again?

Also this does not mean that the **user_id** can be `null`. Since foreign rows are referenced by id (as of your definition) allowing null for this would mean there could be only ONE entry for that.

`Nullable = true` in this case means: You can save a game, with **NO** upto **MANY** users. - But every of the **MANY** users needs to be different to `null` and have an id different to `null`.

Thus, if you call `game.setUsers(null)` - you can save. If you call `game.getUsers().add(null)` - you can't.

Comment: I think you didn't understand. Of course I can save many guests, I don't need any guest info, I just need to know that the guest has played in that game. When I insert manually the null value in the database this works. insert into allin.game_user (game_id, user_id) values(10, null);

Comment: I understood, but i'd say this is not possible. This works manually, but not with hibernate. Hibernate is persisting OBJECTS and accepts null as values - but it can not handle null-objects, because a null-object is "not present" (hibernate would try to save `null.getUserId()` - so to say). Since you do not save ANY information about the guest: Why not add a column `guest_count` to the `game_entity` and increment that if required?

Comment: I had already thought about it but decided to try to save the null values because it did work manually, I thought it would work using hibernate also... Anyway thanks for your help

Comment: I will save the number of players(users.size()) so this way it would be easy to know how many guests I have for each game.

Comment: But then you need to remove null values  from user collection before saving. I would not even add them . If a ENTITY is not of type user - it does not belong into a Collection<User>

Comment: I do not add then. They come from my game server (unity3d) and there I have the class player witch has the attribute user. When I create a new game there I send all users from my players (players.Select(player => player.User)). Maybe I should remove the null users even before send they to my application server.